# CheckBox Function calling a button with IONIC 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm simulating something like a shopping cart using `ionic 2.` Basically you write the item's name and value and it's creating a list with checkbox as in the image below.

[image]

But I wanted the option [image]  only appear when selecting one of the checkboxes, and did not stay static on the screen as it is now. How can I do this?

**grid calling the CheckBox:**

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of produto">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label (click)="clicou(item.desc)">
          {{ item.desc }} {{ item.valor }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

**button code part:**

```
 <button ion-button block (click)="remove()" color="danger" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
        <span class="button-inner">
          <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
          Remover Selecionados
        </span>
        <div class="button-effect"></div>
      </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in ***ts*** create a variable that contains the value of the checks, as an example I will use ***productState*** which will be boolean type, and create in ***produto*** a state.

you can use a ***ngmodel*** and the variable already created (productState) to validate the status of the product, and use the event ***(ionchange)*** to this

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of produto">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label (click)="clicou(item.desc)">
      {{ item.desc }} {{ item.valor }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="validState()" [(ngModel)]="productState" ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

in ***ts*** create a function to valid the state of products:

```
validState(){
let cont = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < this.produto.length; index++) {
  if (this.produto[index].State){
    cont++;
  }  
}
if(cont >=1){
  this.productState = true;
}else{
  this.productState = false;
}
```

}

and in the button we will use **ngIf** to validate the product status through **productState**

```
<button *ngIf="productState" ion-button block (click)="remove()" color="danger" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
    <span class="button-inner">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      Remover Selecionados
    </span>
    <div class="button-effect"></div>
  </button>
```

[ngIf docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)
[ngmodel docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: Almost there! However, it selects all checkboxes. How do I leave only one selected?